# Is it possible to retrieve previous save state of a discarded file on Atom?

Tags: atom-editor

Working on an existing file an entire day and saving it several times before discarding it accidentally, I undoned the discard change but not retrieved the file to it's last state but original one.
Is there a way to retrieve my last save ?
Obviously nothing has been committed...